# How to process JSON object attributes asynchronously using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, promise

I'm having a json object like below

```
var input = {
  "name": "John",
  "email": "asdf@asdf.com",
  "phone": "033343434",
  "address": "123, Bell Street"
}
```

Want to encrypt all the fields like below

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

function encrypt(text) {
    try {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf-8', 'hex');
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
        return crypted;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
function encryptJSON(obj){
    obj.name= encrypt(obj.name);
    obj.email= encrypt(obj.email);
    obj.phone= encrypt(obj.phone);
    obj.address= encrypt(obj.address);
}

console.log(encryptJSON(input));
```

How to encrypt all the fields asynchronously in nodejs using promise or any other?

Comment: does the encrypt function needs to be async? say does it call an API? If not, then you do not need async function

Comment: Yes, make `encrypt` return a promise and use `Promise.all`. Or just `await` each one individually if you want to make it sequential.

Comment: Its not an API call, updated with the encryption logic.. Encryption of all fields should happen in parallel, finally result with encrypted fields.

Comment: @Udhaya parallel? It's *Javascript*. There is no parallel. Not that would matter for this use case anyways.

Comment: why do you need it in parallel? is doing it one by one not suitable for you? looking at your code, everything looks good.. not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Nodejs is single threaded. You cannot do anything in parallel. Promises are for doing something useful while waiting on IO. Encryption is computational, there's nothing to wait for. The code you have is all there is to do.

Comment: I'm having more attributes(40) in the object, so if async(parallel) then it will be faster.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UnknownFragrantRotation

Comment: @Udhaya First you will need to find a crypto library that does encryption in a background thread and tells you about its results asynchronously. Without that, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: dont worry about encryption.. some job to process the attribute.. i want that job to be executed in parallel for all the attributes in a json object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that encrypt returns a promise, you can do it this way:

```
async function encryptJSON(obj){
    const newObject = {};
    const encryptPromises = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
        const value = obj[key];
        return encrypt(value).then((encrypted) => {
            newObject[key] = value;
        });
    });

    await encryptPromises;
    return newObject;
}

encryptJSON(input).then((encrypted) => {
    console.log(encrypted);
});
```

However this doesn't actually make sense unless encrypt returns a promise (which it doesn't appear to be doing). If it doesn't return a promise, JS will just run all the fields in serial anyway (actually the code will break because the return of encrypt isn't thennable so you can't call `then` on it).

If encrypt is taking a long time to run and you want to make all these things run faster, you might want to look into your crypto library and see if there's an async method you can use with the code above.